# Synchronize table between two different databases

Tags: sql-server, laravel, postgresql

Once a day I have to synchronize table between two databases.

> Source: Microsoft SQL Server
>
> Destination: PostgreSQL

Table contains up to 30 million rows.

For the first time i will copy all table, but then for effectiveness my plan is to insert/update only changed rows.

In this way if I delete row from source database, it will not be deleted from the destination database.

The problem is that I don’t know which rows were deleted from the source database.

My dirty thoughts right now tend to use binary search - to compare the sum of the rows on each side and thus catch the deleted rows.

I’m at a dead end - please share your thoughts on this...

Comment: Which RDBMS is the Source and which the Destination?

Comment: Ohh, im sorry, edited question :(

Comment: You don't want to replicate deletes, but you do want to "know" about them?  How do you want this knowledge represented?

Answer (score 1):

with TDS FDWs (Foreign Data Wrapper), map the source table with a temp table in pg, an use a join to find/exclude the rows that you need.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can enable [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) to track which rows are Inserted, Updated, or Deleted since the last time you synchronized the tables.